# Where do I download Ubuntu Touch from?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I'm interested in Ubuntu Touch, but I can't figure out how to download it. Where can I download it from?

Comment: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? afaik it is downloaded when you install.

Answer (score 4):

The install page details how to install Ubuntu for supported devices..

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install

If you want to download the images there's a link in the "Manually Download" section of that page.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install#Manual_Download_.26_Installation